# List unique values grouped by another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, I need to extract the unique values in column B, for every unique value in column A, such that I can construct the following table:

### [image]

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=Unique(A:B)
```

should be enough to return non-duplicate rows

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en

[image]

You can also use Sortn:

```
=sortn(A:B,9E+99,2,1,true,2,true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom, but that doesn't suffice. I need the unique values of column B, but for the subgroup of rows with matching values in column A. See how "x" repeats in column B of the "desired output" section in the example above? That's because there's an "x" for value "1" in column A, and another "x" for value "2" in column A.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, it's my penny that finally dropped, I looked at the the formula you wrote and saw `Unique(B:B)`. It didn't occur to me that I could expand the unique to the combination of both columns. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select A, B, count(A) 
  group by A, B", 1),
 "select Col1, Col2
  where Col1 is not null", 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also install my add-on called [Flookup](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/flookup/593806014962) and use the function below:

```
ULIST(colArray, [indexNum], [threshold])
```

- **colArray** The range from which you want to return unique values.
- **indexNum** The column index to analyse for unique values.
- **threshold** The percentage similarity between the non-unique values. This helps eliminate potential duplicates.

So for your case you would simply type:

```
=ULIST(A1:B6, 2)
```

Find out more details at the [official website](https://www.getflookup.com/tutorial).